# Combinatorial proof of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^2 {n \choose k} = n(n+1)2^{n-2}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Do you know any combinatorial proof of:

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^2 {n \choose k} = n(n+1)2^{n-2}$$?